# Jquery Append and Remove TD content on TR click

Tags: jquery, append, html-table

I'm trying to add an html tag (the green plus icon) when a tr of my table is clicked, i have been able to do that via append but i'm not able to delete the same html tag when i click the same tr again or click another tr on the table.

[Pencode Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WogpRp)

JQUERY

```
      $( document ).ready(function() {
    $( ".results tr" ).click(function(e) {
      $(".results tr").not($(this)).removeClass('current');
      $(".results tr").not($(this)).removeClass('opened');
      $(this).toggleClass('current');
      $(this).find('.add-equipment').toggleClass('opened');
      if ($(this).find('.opened')){
        $(this).find('.opened').append('<i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>');
      }
    });            
  });
```

HTML:

```
              <table class="results table table-outside-border">
            <thead>
              <th><input type="checkbox">UBICACION</th>
              <th>EQUIPO</th>
              </th>
            </thead> 
            <tbody>                 
              <tr>              
                <td width="40%"><input type="checkbox"><a href="#" class="location">Edificio 4</a></td>
                <td width="60%" class="add-equipment"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="inner-content">
                <td colspan="2">
                  <table class="table-equipment">
                    <thead></thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td width="35%"></td>
                        <td width="60%">
                          <p class="client">PANEL_VDF_GSM_UMTS_S3 VODAFONE</p>
                          <p class="equipment">Antena Panel 2.5x0.35, Antena Panel 2.5x0.35, Antena Panel 2.5x0.35, Antena Panel 2.5x0.35</p>
                        </td>
                        <td width="5%" class="icon"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td width="35%"></td>                          
                        <td width="60%">
                          <p class="client">PANEL_VDF_GSM_UMTS_S3 VODAFONE</p>
                          <p class="equipment">Antena Panel 2.5x0.35, Antena Panel 2.5x0.35, Antena Panel 2.5x0.35, Antena Panel 2.5x0.35</p>
                        </td>
                        <td width="5%" class="icon"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td width="35%"></td>                          
                        <td width="60%">
                          <p class="client">PANEL_VDF_GSM_UMTS_S3 VODAFONE</p>
                          <p class="equipment">Antena Panel 2.5x0.35, Antena Panel 2.5x0.35, Antena Panel 2.5x0.35, Antena Panel 2.5x0.35</p>
                        </td>
                        <td width="5%" class="icon"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></td>
                      </tr>                                                    
                    </tbody>
                  </table>  
                </td>                    
              </tr>                  
              <tr>                 
                <td width="40%"><input type="checkbox"><a href="#" class="location">Azotea</a></td>
                <td width="60%" class="add-equipment"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="inner-content">
                <td colspan="2">
                  <table class="table-equipment">
                    <thead></thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td width="35%"></td>
                        <td width="60%">
                          <p class="client">PANEL_VDF_GSM_UMTS_S3 VODAFONE</p>
                          <p class="equipment">Antena Panel 2.5x0.35, Antena Panel 2.5x0.35, Antena Panel 2.5x0.35, Antena Panel 2.5x0.35</p>
                        </td>
                        <td width="5%" class="icon"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td width="35%"></td>                          
                        <td width="60%">
                          <p class="client">PANEL_VDF_GSM_UMTS_S3 VODAFONE</p>
                          <p class="equipment">Antena Panel 2.5x0.35, Antena Panel 2.5x0.35, Antena Panel 2.5x0.35, Antena Panel 2.5x0.35</p>
                        </td>
                        <td width="5%" class="icon"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td width="35%"></td>                          
                        <td width="60%">
                          <p class="client">PANEL_VDF_GSM_UMTS_S3 VODAFONE</p>
                          <p class="equipment">Antena Panel 2.5x0.35, Antena Panel 2.5x0.35, Antena Panel 2.5x0.35, Antena Panel 2.5x0.35</p>
                        </td>
                        <td width="5%" class="icon"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></td>
                      </tr>                                                    
                    </tbody>
                  </table>  
                </td>                    
              </tr>                  
              <tr>
                <td width="40%" class="location"><input type="checkbox"><a href="#">Mástil 1</a></td>
                <td width="60%" class="add-equipment"></td>                    
              </tr>
              <tr class="inner-content">
                <td colspan="2">
                  <table class="table-equipment">
                    <thead></thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td width="35%"></td>
                        <td width="60%">
                          <p class="client">PANEL_VDF_GSM_UMTS_S3 VODAFONE</p>
                          <p class="equipment">Antena Panel 2.5x0.35, Antena Panel 2.5x0.35, Antena Panel 2.5x0.35, Antena Panel 2.5x0.35</p>
                        </td>
                        <td width="5%" class="icon"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td width="35%"></td>                          
                        <td width="60%">
                          <p class="client">PANEL_VDF_GSM_UMTS_S3 VODAFONE</p>
                          <p class="equipment">Antena Panel 2.5x0.35, Antena Panel 2.5x0.35, Antena Panel 2.5x0.35, Antena Panel 2.5x0.35</p>
                        </td>
                        <td width="5%" class="icon"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td width="35%"></td>                          
                        <td width="60%">
                          <p class="client">PANEL_VDF_GSM_UMTS_S3 VODAFONE</p>
                          <p class="equipment">Antena Panel 2.5x0.35, Antena Panel 2.5x0.35, Antena Panel 2.5x0.35, Antena Panel 2.5x0.35</p>
                        </td>
                        <td width="5%" class="icon"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></td>
                      </tr>                                                    
                    </tbody>
                  </table>  
                </td>                    
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="40%"><input type="checkbox"><a href="#" class="location">Tripode Autosoportado ORG1</a></td>
                <td width="60%" class="add-equipment"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="inner-content">
                <td colspan="2">
                  <table class="table-equipment">
                    <thead></thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td width="35%"></td>
                        <td width="60%">
                          <p class="client">PANEL_VDF_GSM_UMTS_S3 VODAFONE</p>
                          <p class="equipment">Antena Panel 2.5x0.35, Antena Panel 2.5x0.35, Antena Panel 2.5x0.35, Antena Panel 2.5x0.35</p>
                        </td>
                        <td width="5%" class="icon"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td width="35%"></td>                          
                        <td width="60%">
                          <p class="client">PANEL_VDF_GSM_UMTS_S3 VODAFONE</p>
                          <p class="equipment">Antena Panel 2.5x0.35, Antena Panel 2.5x0.35, Antena Panel 2.5x0.35, Antena Panel 2.5x0.35</p>
                        </td>
                        <td width="5%" class="icon"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td width="35%"></td>                          
                        <td width="60%">
                          <p class="client">PANEL_VDF_GSM_UMTS_S3 VODAFONE</p>
                          <p class="equipment">Antena Panel 2.5x0.35, Antena Panel 2.5x0.35, Antena Panel 2.5x0.35, Antena Panel 2.5x0.35</p>
                        </td>
                        <td width="5%" class="icon"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></td>
                      </tr>                                                    
                    </tbody>
                  </table>  
                </td>                    
              </tr>                  
              <tr>                 
                <td width="40%"><input type="checkbox"><a href="#" class="location">Mástil 3</a></td>
                <td width="60%" class="add-equipment"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="inner-content">
                <td colspan="2">
                  <table class="table-equipment">
                    <thead></thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td width="35%"></td>
                        <td width="60%">
                          <p class="client">PANEL_VDF_GSM_UMTS_S3 VODAFONE</p>
                          <p class="equipment">Antena Panel 2.5x0.35, Antena Panel 2.5x0.35, Antena Panel 2.5x0.35, Antena Panel 2.5x0.35</p>
                        </td>
                        <td width="5%" class="icon"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td width="35%"></td>                          
                        <td width="60%">
                          <p class="client">PANEL_VDF_GSM_UMTS_S3 VODAFONE</p>
                          <p class="equipment">Antena Panel 2.5x0.35, Antena Panel 2.5x0.35, Antena Panel 2.5x0.35, Antena Panel 2.5x0.35</p>
                        </td>
                        <td width="5%" class="icon"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td width="35%"></td>                          
                        <td width="60%">
                          <p class="client">PANEL_VDF_GSM_UMTS_S3 VODAFONE</p>
                          <p class="equipment">Antena Panel 2.5x0.35, Antena Panel 2.5x0.35, Antena Panel 2.5x0.35, Antena Panel 2.5x0.35</p>
                        </td>
                        <td width="5%" class="icon"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></td>
                      </tr>                                                    
                    </tbody>
                  </table>  
                </td>                    
              </tr>                  
              <tr>                 
                <td width="40%"><input type="checkbox"><a href="#" class="location">Mástil 2</a></td>
                <td width="60%" class="add-equipment"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="inner-content">
                <td colspan="2">
                  <table class="table-equipment">
                    <thead></thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td width="35%"></td>
                        <td width="60%">
                          <p class="client">PANEL_VDF_GSM_UMTS_S3 VODAFONE</p>
                          <p class="equipment">Antena Panel 2.5x0.35, Antena Panel 2.5x0.35, Antena Panel 2.5x0.35, Antena Panel 2.5x0.35</p>
                        </td>
                        <td width="5%" class="icon"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td width="35%"></td>                          
                        <td width="60%">
                          <p class="client">PANEL_VDF_GSM_UMTS_S3 VODAFONE</p>
                          <p class="equipment">Antena Panel 2.5x0.35, Antena Panel 2.5x0.35, Antena Panel 2.5x0.35, Antena Panel 2.5x0.35</p>
                        </td>
                        <td width="5%" class="icon"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td width="35%"></td>                          
                        <td width="60%">
                          <p class="client">PANEL_VDF_GSM_UMTS_S3 VODAFONE</p>
                          <p class="equipment">Antena Panel 2.5x0.35, Antena Panel 2.5x0.35, Antena Panel 2.5x0.35, Antena Panel 2.5x0.35</p>
                        </td>
                        <td width="5%" class="icon"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></td>
                      </tr>                                                    
                    </tbody>
                  </table>  
                </td>                    
              </tr>                                                                                 
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

SASS:

```
.inner-content {
display:none;
td:first-child {
    border-top:none !important;
}   
}
.results {
    table-layout:fixed;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    td, th {
        border-right:1px solid #c7c7c7;
        &:last-child {
            border-right:none;
        }
    }
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse!important;
    font-size:14px;
    width: 100%;
    thead {
        border-bottom:2px solid #ddd;
        tr {
            th {
                &:nth-child(1) {
                    width:35.125%;
                }
                &:nth-child(2) {
                    width:65%;
                }               
                padding-left:8px;
                text-align:left;
                input[type=checkbox] {
                    vertical-align: middle;
                    margin-right:10px;
                    margin-top:0;
                }                               
            }
        }   
    }
    tbody {
        td {
            &.add-equipment {
                color:#2b8e00;
                font-size:18px;
                text-align:right;
            }   
            border-bottom:1px solid #c7c7c7;
            padding-left:8px;
            a {
                vertical-align: middle;
                &:hover, &:active, &:visited {
                    text-decoration: none;
                }
            }
            input[type=checkbox] {
                vertical-align: middle;
                margin-right:10px;
                margin-top:0;
            }       
        }
    }
    .current {
        background-color: #eee !important;
        .location {
            font-weight: 700;
        }
        + tr {
            display:table-row;
            td {
                padding:0;
                &:last-child {
                    padding-right:0;
                    padding-bottom:0;
                }
                .table-equipment {
                    background-color:#eee;
                    border-collapse:collapse;
                    table-layout:fixed;                 
                    p {
                        line-height: 10px;
                        &:last-child {
                            margin-bottom:0;
                        }
                    }
                    td {
                        border-right:1px solid #c7c7c7;
                        padding:20px 0 20px 10px;
                        vertical-align: middle;
                        &:last-child {
                            border-right:none;
                        }                       
                        &.icon {
                            padding:0 10px 0 10px !important;
                            text-align:center;
                        }

                    }
                    tr {
                        &:last-child {
                            td {
                                border-bottom:none;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .client {
                        color: #40576a;
                        font-weight: 600;
                    }
                    .equipment {
                        color: #7f8080;
                        font-size: 14px;        
                        line-height: 15px;
                        @media only screen and (min-width:768px) {
                            line-height: 15px;
                        }
                    }
                    .fa-exclamation-triangle {
                        color:red;
                        font-size:18px;
                    }
                }
            }
        }       
    }
}
.table-outside-border {
    border:1px solid #e1e1e1;
}
.table-results-audits {
    .box {
        padding:20px 10px;
    }
    label {
        font-weight: normal;
    }
    select {
        display:inline-block;
        width:70px;
    }
    input {
        margin-left: 0.5em;
        display: inline-block;
        width: auto;
    }
    ul {
        margin:0;
    }
    .dataTables_filter, .dataTables_paginate {
        text-align:right;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    .input-sm {
        height: 30px;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        font-size: 12px;
        line-height: 1.5;
        border-radius: 3px;
        padding-top:0;
        padding-bottom:0;
    }
    .table-controls {
        overflow: hidden;
        margin-bottom:10px;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You just need to remove the i icon from your table. You can try the following code:

 $( document ).ready(function() {
    $( ".results tr" ).click(function(e) {
      $(".results tr").not($(this)).removeClass('current');
      $(".results tr").not($(this)).removeClass('opened');
      $(".results tr").not($(this)).find('.add-equipment').removeClass('opened');
      $(this).toggleClass('current');
      $(this).find('.add-equipment').toggleClass('opened');
      $('.results i.fa-plus-square').remove(); //add this line
      if ($(this).find('.opened')){
        $(this).find('.opened').append('<i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>');
      }
    });            
  });
```

Comment: Great, thanks Himanshu it worked. Just a question, is there a more clean way to do this ? i'm trying to keep my code as clean as i can and any advice about that will be really appreciated.

Comment: i have updated my codepen with your line (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WogpRp), it works fine  but i have just realized that if you start clicking different TR'S when the inner table is opened at some point the plus icon won't show up. Do you know whats happening ?

Comment: Hi @Himanshu (or anybody that can help), ive been dealing with this issue for days and can't find a solution yet, everything is working fine with the jquery but i have realized that when a TR is opened and i click on a close TR it will open it but the plus icon won't show up again, apparently this happen when you click on the table more than once, if somebody can help that will be really helpful.

Comment: Hi @Lowtrux I have updated the answer you can check now

Answer (score 0):

try remove all icons when tr clicked

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        $( ".results tr" ).click(function(e) {
          $('.plusIcon').remove(); //i added plusIcon class to your icon
          $(".results tr").not($(this)).removeClass('current');
          $(".results tr").not($(this)).removeClass('opened');
          $(this).toggleClass('current');
          $(this).find('.add-equipment').toggleClass('opened');
          if ($(this).find('.opened')){
            $(this).find('.opened').append('<i class="fa fa-plus-square plusIcon"></i>');
          }
        });            
      });
```